# Export Kubernetes Logs from Argo

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I am working in a setup where I have an Argo CD portal to view the Kubernetes deployments etc. But do not have access to a kubeconfig file (hence cannot use kubectl).

I can see the logs for the pods in the web UI, but is there a way to export the logs as a text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArgoCD's logging interface in >2.0 includes a Download button.

For earlier versions, open your browser's dev tools to the Network tab. Click the Logs tag in the ArgoCD interface. Find the network request to the `logs` endpoint and open the URL in a new tab. From there you can download the logs as a text file using your browser's "Save As" feature.

Comment: Thanks Michael. This was exactly what I was looking for. My argo version is <2.0 since I do not see a 'Download' button. But I needed to search and copy some text from the logs, which I can do based on what you recommended